# How to query a third relation in Ecto Associations

Tags: elixir, ecto

```
Snapmail
|> preload(:user)
|> preload(:snapmail_cameras)
|> preload([snapmail_cameras: :camera])
|> preload([snapmail_cameras: [camera: :vendor_model]])
|> preload([snapmail_cameras: [camera: [vendor_model: :vendor]]])
|> Repo.all
```

I have above query in Ecto. in this. Each `snapmail` has a `snapmail_camera` and `snapmail_camera`has a `camera_id` which is camera's `id` (from camera table.)

and Cameras table has a field `status`.

I am trying to get only those `snapmails` where its `snapmail_cameras`'s camera's status is not equal to `project_finished`

this is the relation of `snapmail` and `snapmail_camera`

```
belongs_to :user, User, foreign_key: :user_id
has_many :snapmail_cameras, SnapmailCamera
```

any help would be so thankful. How I can get those `snapmails`?

Answer (score 1):

You're preloading a ton, which will get you lots of data you could filter our in code, but the database can return much less data if you use [`join/5`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#join/5):

Assuming I've interpreted your scheme correctly, here's what I'd do.

```
import Ecto.Query

query =
  from s in MyApp.Snapmail,
  join: sc in assoc(s, :snapmail_cameras),
  join: c in assoc(sc, :camera),
  where: c.status != ^"status_finished"

MyApp.Repo.all(query)
```

This will only return `Snapmails` without all those preloads, but you can always add a [`preload/3'](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3) at the end of your query to bring that data in.

Answer (score -1):

Executing

```
Snapmail |> Repo.preload([snapmail_cameras: :camera]) |> Repo.all()
```

Returns a list containing all Snapmails: `[%Snapmail{},...]`

Each Snapmail struct would look like this

```
%Snapmail{
 snapmail_cameras: [
  %SnapmailCamera{
     camera: %Camera{
               status: "status" 
             }
   }, ... 
 ]
}
```

At this point, you could use the filter function

```
Enum.filter(snapmails, 
fn snapmail-> snapmail.snapmail_cameras 
|> Enum.all?(fn snapmail_camera -> snapmail_camera.status != "project_finished" end) 
end)
```

Comment: status is not equal to project_finished

Comment: This is extremely wrong. Loading the whole database into memory and sorting / filtering outside of the database is a direct road to OOM. Imagine you have a billion records in the DB.

Comment: Yap, you're right. I did not imagine of that scenario