# Shall I use changeset when update existing data in Ecto?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have function in changeset pipeline to encrypt token.

```
def changeset(user, params \\ %{}) do
  user
  |> cast(params, [:id, :token]
  |> encrypt(:token)
end
```

Since this function is new, the old data is still not encrypted and I need to do it manually. Then I met the problem.

If I pass the original `token` to changeset, it will treat the value as if no changes. The `encrypt` in pipeline is not working and value not update.

If I encrypted the `token` and pass to changeset, it marked as changes, and `encrypt` function applied. However, it encrypted `twice`.

One clumsy way is to add a checking on `encrypt` to check if the `token` is encrypted or not. But remember before we passed new token to changeset, we still need to check if the token is encrypted. Which means, we do the checking twice.

So I'm looking for a simple solution if someone have the idea.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a run-once action, I would go with a migration, that directly calls [`Ecto.Repo.update/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html?#c:update/2) (unfortunately I did not find a way to call [`Ecto.Repo.update_all/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html?#c:update_all/3) here unless you can do `encrypt` directly in the database.)

```
defmodule My.Repo.Migrations.EncryptTokens do
  @moduledoc false
  use Ecto.Migration

  def up do
    for unencrypted <- from(...) |> Repo.all() do
      unencrypted
      |> Ecto.Changeset.change(token: encrypt(unencrypted.token))
      |> Repo.update()
    end
  end
  def down, do: raise "unrevertable"
end
```

---

*Sidenote:* you might also take a look at [`Ecto.Changeset.force_change/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#force_change/3) fwiw.

Comment: would you take a look here pls? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57680929/how-to-query-a-third-relation-in-ecto-associations

Comment: @JunaidFarooq what’s wrong with the answer given by Lanny Bose? It seems to be correct.

Comment: it's not loading `vendor_model: :vendor]` associations.

Comment: Thanks @AlekseiMatiushkin, you are right, my update should go internal way, which  using `change` and `force_change` instead of `changeset` function in Model(with `cast`).